# CSS Remove table's border

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Template installed so the table takes the style that was given. I managed to change tables color for background and text but I couldn't remove the frame around the table (border). I found a lot of related results but I couldn't find something that worked for me (I'm not that much experienced with CSS).

```css
body {
  background: #040404;
}

table.photos_table td {
  background-color: #040404 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
table.photos_table {
  border: none !important;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="photos_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>food</td>
      <td>drink</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>pizza</td>
      <td>soda</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I get as a result.

[image: Border is still visible]

Any suggestions what could be wrong? Do I need an other option?

Comment: Looks like you are unable to replicate it here? Can you some how replicate the issue, so that we can look into it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar This is the website if you want to take a better look. www.moiloungebar.gr/φωτογραφίες. Do you need any more infos? (not  sure what you asked for :S)

Comment: That would be helpful.

Comment: I have solved it... Kindly check and update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border` is in the `<tbody>`, so giving:

```
table thead, table tbody, table tfoot {border: none;}
```

Works...

[image: preview]

Comment: Thank you very much! I will mark your answer as right in 2 minutes!

Comment: @marduc812 You are welcome. Make sure you provide the right information for us to debug. In this case, you could have provided the website. `:)` Happy that you got it working.

Answer (score -1):

Check for border attribute in style.css file. 
I am assuming border has been assigned to either td or tr attribute in style.css file.

This should fix it.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Is'nt your answer what I said in the first place ? 
Plus, I am not allowed to comment (reputation points<50), hence the answer.
Anyways, I was just trying to help. Good that it worked

Comment: You just assumed something right and didn't give the right answer. `:)`